# caret/negate for a word in regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

`[^a-zA-Z]` matches anything except `a, b, c, .. z, A, B, .. Z`

I want the expression that matches anything except `(abc)` **and** except `(xyz)`

I want a regex for image tag.

I tried `img.*src` - it matches the initial part but between `img` and `src` there should not be any other image tag so I put a caret `img[^(neither <img nor src=)]` how to use `^` with a group of characters?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: what exactly are you doing, and in what language?

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, why don't you just make sure the "src" is inside the same tag?

Do something like `<img\s[^>]*\bsrc`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the scenario you're describing, it sounds like you want to use a look-ahead instead of a character exclusion.

```
MatchThis\s*(?!DontMatchThis|OrThis)
```

This will match "MatchThis", but not if it is is followed by "DontMatchThis" or by "OrThis"

Here's a link if you'd like to learn more about look-aheads and look-behinds in regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html